# Stuck in infinite loop when trying to break a while loop

Tags: c++, function, loops

So I am making a calculator with a main menu that I want the operation to continue until the user presses $ and then goes back to the main menu. When I test it, it throws my code in an infinite loop. What did I do wrong? Below is a snippet of one function. (menu is declared as void)

```
float makeSum(float num1, float num2) {

float r = 0;
bool ended = false;
do {
    cout << "Please provide the first number: " << endl;
    cin >> num1;

    if (num1 == '$') {
        ended = true;
    }

    cout << "Please provide the second number: " << endl;
    cin >> num2;

    if (num2 == '$') {
        ended = true;

    r = num1 + num2;
    cout << "Result: " << r << endl;
} while (!ended);

menu();
return r;

}
```

Comment: The function you show should not build, it's missing a closing brace `}`.

Comment: In what circumstance would you expect a value of type `float`, read from the user, to test as equal to `'$'`?    It is certainly not if the user enters a `$`, since streaming operators don't know how to convert that to a floating point value.     If your implementation uses the ASCII character set (or one compatible with it), entering the value `36` will cause the loop to end, because `36` is the integral value of `'$'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not going to work for sure. When you say:

```
float num2;
```

and then later:

```
cin >> num2;
```

Then only floats will be read from the input stream. One way out of this is to have, inside your loop:

```
string input;
...
cin >> input;
if (input == "$") break;
istringstream s(input);
float num;
s >> num; // now you read a float from the string
```

Another thing is that it is just easier to break out of a loop using `break` as I have shown in the code snippet above, instead of using a boolean flag and checking for it.

Comment: furthermore, you should always test the state of cin, because if it fails, you're going to have inputs that you don't want, so your checks will fail (most of the time).

Comment: `float num = std::stof(input)` would be easier to read than using an `istringstream` IMO.

Comment: @kevr There is a lot to be improved, I tried to answer the question as it stands. There is plenty of code examples here on Stackoverflow and elsewhere.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Absolutely, just wanted to break it down so that the logical error in the code becomes obvious. You are most welcome to edit my answer if you feel it will improve it (see also my comment to kevr).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude BTW, your suggestion still breaks if the string is neither "$" nor a valid float.

Comment: The [`std::stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) function can be used for error checking very easily. And yes you still should do that explicit check against `"$"` first.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It seems to me you'd have to use exceptions for this or check for a NaN; is that so?

Comment: Yes that's correct. That's why the check for `"$"` should still be done first.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Well then, still quite a bit more than what the question deserves as it stands....

Comment: The s is incomplete type according to Visual Studio?

Comment: @DerekH as most simplistic code examples in C++, I assume you have `#include`d the correct headers and said `using namespace std;`. You will need at least `#include <string>` and then `std::string` instead of `string` only if you don't want to polute your namespace. You will probably also need `#include <sstream>` and `std::istringstream` instead of `istringstream`. Please consult the documentation.

Comment: @DerekH BTW, in the book on C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup there is a somewhat complete example of a calculator.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I should've immediately recognized the floating point comparison!